# Getting duplicated records in MySQL trying to get data from two different tables

Tags: mysql, distinct

I am doing a MySQL query which has to return all records from a table and add dynamically two columns, one is taking the value from other table and the last value is evaluating if a record exists in other table and returning true or false depending on it.

Let me explain a little bit better:

I have a table which stores information about books ( bookid, bookname, bookdescription ) there aren't any duplicated record in this table.
I have a second table which stores a relation between users and those books ( it stores the reference to the book, the reference to the user ID, if this book is default and the rating of the book )

*This is how my query looks like right now:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*,
  IF(ub.ub_bookid is not NULL AND ub.ub_userid = :userid , ub.ub_default, 0) AS "default",
  IF(ub.ub_bookid is not NULL AND ub.ub_userid = :userid , True, False) AS "visible"
FROM `books` as b LEFT JOIN `users_books` as ub
ON ub.ub_bookid = b.b_id;
```

> (Since I am doing the query from PHP with PDO the value :userid is given at the execution time)

The above query pretends to return all books from the book table, and for each book see if in the table users_books there is a record with the given userid, in case that it exists it will return the value of default and return a true in the "active" column. In the case that the record doesn't exists it will return a false has default and false as "active".

**My Problem:** When I have more than 2 relations with the same book but different users the query is returning duplicated entries. If I remove the `DISTINCT` the query returns duplicated entries if there is more than one record for the same book ( but obviously different user ids ).

I am not really sure how to return only as many records as the books table has and avoid duplicating them. I've been trying to use `GROUP BY` in order to achieve this but couldn't do it since the query fails when I use it.

Any advice or help will be so appreciated. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along those lines (Not sure I completely understood what you want)?

```
SELECT b.*,
    IF(ub.ub_bookid IS NOT NULL, ub.ub_default, 0) AS 'default',
    IF(ub.ub_bookid IS NOT NULL, True, False) AS 'visible'
FROM books b
LEFT JOIN users_books ub ON b.b_id = ub.ub_bookid AND ub.ub_userid = :userid
```

Comment: What you mean? I already solved the question adding the `AND ub.ub_userid = :userid` after the ON. That avoid me to getting duplicated entries ^^

Comment: This answer is a bit cleaner than in terms of removing redundant checks. Also 'Distinct' is pretty heavy operation and should be avoided if possble

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see the difference. Thanks for the help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Well after some hours of work, I posted this and in 8 minutes testing with phpmyadmin I finally found a way of avoiding the duplicated records. I only needed to add and AND at the JOIN ON (which I didn't know that was possible). Now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.*,
  IF(ub.ub_bookid is not NULL AND ub.ub_userid = :userid , ub.ub_default, 0) AS "default",
  IF(ub.ub_bookid is not NULL AND ub.ub_userid = :userid , True, False) AS "visible"
FROM `books` as b LEFT JOIN `users_books` as ub
ON ub.ub_bookid = b.b_id AND ub.ub_userid = :userid;
```